# android request a php web service using HttpURLConnection and submit the php form

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I want to parse a php web service using my android application, I create a connection to the url like this

```
InputStream stream = null ;
URL url = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn;
conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
stream =conn.getInputStream();
```

after `getInputStream` , I am using pull parser to parse xml data, but my problem is the web service requires to submit the form to get xml data. How can I click this button from my java code? Is this possible or do I need to change the web service ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps if you want to read data from webservide:
In your button's onclick listener

```
new urlConTask().execute() //use asynctask
```

in asynctask's doInBackground method:

```
   @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String url = ur url here;
            String response = "";
            try {
                 response = HttpConnect.sendGet(url);//sendGet is method defined in HttpConnect.java. Its a custom class

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

sendGetMethod:

```
   public static String  sendGet(String url) throws Exception {



        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        return response.toString(); //this is your response

    }
```

Comment: this is not my problem, my problem is on the web service, when i request it i need to click submit button on it to get the xml data that i want to parse, the submit button submit all the form

Comment: I am not getiing your point. You want a submit button to get xml date from web server?

Comment: the web service does not return xml data directly, it requires to click a submit button before getting xml data, in my android code i can't access the necessary data because i cant click this button, my question is it is possible to click the submit button on the web service from my android code? or i must change the web service

Answer (score 1):

Your app will not be abled to "click" submit button. You said that the submit button submit all the form. Your app should do the request triggered by the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

I must change the web service and make it GET and POST, then i my code I must put

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
```